# Is there a way to write client script that greys out a sublist field column (Netsuite 2.0)?

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript, sublist, customising

I have a request to grey out a sub-list column.  I tried a Client Script Type but I am unable to set the display. Any advise would appreciated.

Comment: By grey do you mean disabled?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what you want to achieve, but remember that you can do ***native javascript*** or ***jQuery*** on a Client Script, that may help you to do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If by greyed out you mean disabled as the comments suggest, it is possible by Client Script in SuiteScript 2.0.

You will use currentRecord.getSublistField(...).isDisabled = true.

If you are willing to show your attempts, I am happy to follow-up and assist you further.